# Unzip specific zip file from nested zip file using ANT

Tags: java, build, ant, zip

I have a zip file ex. 'test.zip' that contains 2 more zip files within it - A.zip and B.zip. I want to only extract contents of A.zip and leave B.zip untouched.

I did try out the below code snippet, but found no luck yet -

```
<unzip src="test.zip" dest="test_dir">
            <fileset dir="test_dir">
                <include name="A.zip"/>
                <exclude name="B.zip"/>
            </fileset>
        </unzip>
```

Please advise how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the unzip task’s documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html):

> Only file system based resource collections are supported by Unjar/Unwar/Unzip, this includes fileset, filelist, path, and files.

This means you have to have a physical copy of A.zip somewhere on the file system.

So, there really is no choice other than doing it in two steps:

```
<tempfile property="a" suffix=".zip"/>
<copy tofile="${a}">
    <zipentry zipfile="test.zip" name="A.zip"/>
</copy>

<unzip src="${a}" dest="test_dir"/>
<delete file="${a}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

***PatternSets*** are used to select files to extract from the archive. If no patternset is used, all files are extracted.

***FileSets*** may be used used to select archived files to perform unarchival upon.

**Try this:**

```
<unzip src="test.zip" dest="test_dir">
            <patternset>
                <include name="A.zip"/>
            </patternset>
            <fileset dir="test_dir">
                <include name="A.zip"/>
            </fileset>
        </unzip>
```

Comment: The nested fileset will not look *inside* test.zip. It will look for an existing A.zip in test_dir.

Comment: @fatalcoder524 - I tried this, but though 'A.zip' did get extracted from 'test.zip', 'A.zip' itself didn't get extracted.

Comment: @VGR - yes that's what seems to be happening. Any means of doing the extraction of 'A.zip' itself in that same step ?